# How can I read data from my static HTML page, such as the meta tag?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 application that is using Flask (Python framework) to serve up the contents of my static HTML to the browser when the index is accessed. What I want to do is display the version of my application in my `AboutComponent`. I currently have Flask rendering the version into my HTML via a meta tag (`<meta name="version" content="{{ version }}">`).

My initial attempt was to create an input into my `AppComponent` (root component) component (which I would then pass into my `AboutComponent`, but I've learned that such thing is not possible.

Having that said, how can I access an HTML's meta tag within a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@onetwothree - If you simply want to access it's content it would be something like this.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
    private appVersion:string;
    constructor(){
        this.appVersion = "";
    }
    // Runs on component creation
    ngOnInit(){
       this.appVersion = this.getMetaData();
    }
    getMetaData():string{
       return document.getElementByName("version")[0].content; 
       //=== "what ever the version you passed in your FLASK template"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more Angular-like way would be to use the DomAdapter

```
import 'package:angular2/platform/browser.dart' show BrowserDomAdapter;
```

Sorry, I don't know how to translate this import to TS.

```
MyComponent {
  constructor(private dom: BrowserDomAdapter ) {
    dom.querySelector('meta[name="version"]').getAttribute('content');
  }
}
```

Comment: While I agree that this solution is more Angualr-like, it doesn't work. It throws an error saying that `querySelector` isn't a function on `undefined`. Looking at the API for `querySelector` it requires an element, which in my case needs to be `document`.

Comment: The docs don't tell much. It looks like you need to call `BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent();` I guess before `bootstrap()` at least before you use it.